# Eliminating hazards from USB PD

Tags: usb, usb-pd

I have a very good multiport GaN charger, which I use for charging multiple devices simultaneously:
[image]

To make it even more universal I bought these magnetic cables with magnetic heads, to reduce the number of different cables I have to bring along:
[image]

I works very good, but as always, it has a massive drawback: yesterday I was charging one single device at 12V (PD), and when I disconnected the cable from the magnetic head, the charger's port has been died. 2 other ports of it are still okay, but the first one is completely dead.

This was surely caused by some hazard, and I know this is somewhat impossible to solve without proper equipments (I.e. oscilloscope). However, what I have to do to properly detect this killer hazard is to have a scope applied to each pin of the USBC connector, while trying to kill the charger.

USBC has many pins, this is the partial (USB2.0) pinout of my magnetic head:
[image]

Magnet on the side is conducting, but it is not connected to anything on the other side. However it can short these pins accidentally.

I wish to protect the charger from these below problems:

- accidentally shorting two pins for a short time (below 1s)
- disconnection of all pins (including vbus, cc, SBU, gnd) at either (a) same time or (b) not the correct order which USB requires.

I found good materials like this: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slvaf82

It recommends using TVS2200 on VBUS line, and other surge protection circuits on other lines.

My idea is to design a small PCB with one C plug and one C receptacle, and apply the protection circuit in between them.

Unfortunately I don't have the circuit of the charger but it has a lot of protection inside like overvoltage, overcurrent, temperature, etc.

On the magnetic head, there are 2 pins which I haven't marked, these are the CC and SBU pins (as these cables can be used for PD, but not for Alt Mode, etc).

So technically, it is possible for a short time to short VBUS and one of these:

- D+
- D-
- CC
- SBU

I believe the charger does nothing with D+ and D-, however it is using CC (and maybe SBU) massively for managing PD.

I also think and assume that shorting either CC or SBU to GND shall not cause any harm normally to the charger.

So the only valid cause seems shorting high voltage VBUS to CC or SBU.

This way I reduced my goal to apply protection against this criteria, and against disconnecting the pins in wrong order.

I would really appreciate any help, study, material, circuit which can be useful.

NB: this hazard killed another branded charger (Hyperjuice), therefore I assume chargers are simply not protected against this effect. So, recommendation of buying another charger is no-go, and I prefer not dropping these cables, as anyway these are really convenient.

Comment: I think the problem is the magnetic connector interface bypasses the correct sequence of plugging and unplugging the USB wires. You might end up the ground getting disconnected first or mated last so possible supply return path may be via data or other pins - which can even blow up ESD protections. Yes, devices are not prepared for handling these kinds of problems because the devices don't expect to be in situations not allowed in specifications. So you are simply trying to work around the problem created by using the magnetic connectors in the first place. It could have fried the phone/laptop

Comment: Close reason, brave noname?

Comment: @Justme: the purpose of my question is to overcome on this problem. I know ESD might not help, so I would like to focus more on what *could* help rather than what *can't* :)

Comment: @Daniel If you could change the pins to pogo pins of sufficient current rating with the longest ones being for ground, then slightly shorter ones for +, and finally the shortest ones for data then they would connect and disconnect in the safe order, I think.

Comment: The main problem is that factories make unsafe non-compliant cables and people buy and want to use them. You can never make them universally safe by just adding protection components between charger and magnetic cable, because USB-C handles the safe insertion sequence with mechanical design, which this is unable to do. To me, you have only identified a subset of the possible problems that can happen with these magnetic cables.It can be made safer, but not safe.

Comment: One more interesting comment: these corruptions *only* happened when there were higher voltages negotiated (12 or 15 or 20V). Not every time, I.e. I used higher voltages N times, and 5% of N there were corruptions. With 5V devices, 0% corruption.